# How to use my previous ML model to predict on new test corpus?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

So, basically I have a test corpus of **350** text files (**350 rows**) and I made a ml model to predict the gender of an author based on the SMS in each text file.

After preprocessing is done these are my final lines of code :

(**Joined** is preprocessed column in dataframe df)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
y = df['Gender']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
                                         df['Joined'], y, 
                                         test_size=0.20,random_state=53)

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
count_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train.values)
count_test = count_vectorizer.transform(X_test.values)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()
nb_classifier.fit(count_train, y_train)
pred = nb_classifier.predict(count_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
```

Now I have a new test corpus which has **150** text files(**150 rows**) and I have to predict the gender of these files based on my previous model!

I have made a new dataframe called `newdf` and preprocessed the test corpus files into a column called `new_test` which has **150 rows**.

Now how can I use my previous `nb_classifier` model on this `new_test` column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have pre-processed `new_test` the same way you did `count_test` you would simply call `nb_classifier.predict` or `predict_proba` and pass in your `new_test` array.

I prefer `predict_proba` as it returns the probability of each class rather than a single prediction.

#### Update Per Comments

It would appear you have a dimensionality issue. When you train your MultinomialNB classifier it can only process data that is passed in with the same dimensions as that upon which it was trained. For example:

You created training data with n samples and m features by using CountVectorizer. Any data passed into your classifier must conform to having m features or the classifier will not understand how to process this discrepancy.

As such it is critical that when using a CountVectorizer for pre-processing you also use that fitted instance to transform any data upon which you wish to predict.

In code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'joined': [
        'a sentence', 'This is some great food',
        'the quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog'],
    'label': ['M', 'F', 'M']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'new_text': [
        'a differenct sentence',
        'something entirely different that hasnt been seen before',
        'fox and dog'],
    'label': ['M', 'M', 'F']})

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
count_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(df.joined.values)

nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()
nb_classifier.fit(count_train, df.label)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, pred)

new_test = count_vectorizer.transform(df2.new_text.values)
nb_classifier.predict_proba(new_test)
array([[0.27272727, 0.72727273],
       [0.33333333, 0.66666667],
       [0.2195122 , 0.7804878 ]])
```

Comment: yes I did exactly the same but is showing dimension error

Comment: what is the output of `count_test.shape` and `new_test.shape`?

Comment: count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english') count_test_new=count_vect.transform(newDF['new_test'].values) -> This is how i processed new_test column

Comment: count_test has shape (70, 18567) and count_test_new has shape (150, 14304)

Comment: It would seem you are using a different CountVectorizer for your `new_test` values. If you use the one that you fit on `X_train` to transform the new values, the number of features will be the same.

Comment: Oh! So I have to use **count_vectorizer** with a fit method or only transform method?

Comment: count_vect_test= count_vectorizer.transform(newDF['new_test'].values)
nb_classifier.predict_proba(count_vect_test) I did this but still dimension mismatch

Comment: some things I want to clear **new_test** is a column.

Comment: I hope you didnt misunderstood new_test as a name for count_vectorizer

Comment: I would have to guess you used a `fit` method on `count_vectorizer` somewhere in between. Once you fit, the vocabulary is set. This is what sets the number of features output by the vectorizer. Have you tried the example that I included in answer?

Comment: any help? I am stuck with this problem and I have a deadline also there is no one to help me!

Comment: Thanks for explaining this but I have only 1 column in df2 i.e no label in that!

Comment: I re-ran the notebook but still dimension mismatch error. I did exactly the same steps you have mentioned.

Comment: Well i hate to tell you, but unless you are refitting `count_vectorizer` no matter what you transform the number of features will be the same. You might check your `count_vectorizer.vocabulary_` as it should not change. If it has you have refit somewhere you did not intend.

Comment: As in your code, you have taken labels in the second data frame whereas in my second data frame I don't have labels for male and female so will it make a difference

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED!  Somehow I was refitting it as you said.